# Ending a function while continuing from that point reading a file

Tags: c++, file

I've wrote a program which reads a textfile character for character and counts the amount of vowels that pass. However if a symbol, say "*" appears, I want the program to stop counting the vowels and start counting the non-vowels, obviously continuing from that point forward. I've written a different function and entered the following:

```
if (kar == '*'){
        reversecounting(i);
        return 0;
}
```

Where reversecounting is the int-function counting non-vowels.
The problem I'm having right now is that whenever it does this, the function counting the non-vowels starts at the beginning of the file. Is there a way to make it continu on from the point where the other function stopped?

I'm using the "get"-function to read from the file. Thanks in advance.

Edit: sorry for not including relevant code, I've added it now and some commentary to make it understandable

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int countnonvowels( int &k ); //prototype

int countvowels( int k ){ //start function to count vowels
ifstream input; //to open textfile
char kar;      // this is the character that will be read
int countvowels = 0; //local counter of vowels


input.open ("input.txt",ios::in); //opening the textfile


    kar = input.get ( ); //first obtain a character from the textfile
    while ( ! input.eof ( ) ) { //reads the file untile end of file
        kar = input.get ( ); //the next character in the file gets "read"

      if( kar == 'e' or kar == 'a' or kar == 'i' or kar == 'o' or kar == 'u' ){ //checks whether the character is a vowel
            countvowels++; //local counter goes up by one
            kar = input.get(); //take the next letter and print it
            cout << kar << " " << countvowels << endl;
            countvowels = 0; //value becomes zero again
      }//if
      if (kar == '*'){ //if the character is a "*", I want the non-vowels to be counted and the k-th non-vowel to be printed
            countnonvowels(k);
            return 0; //this function has to stop running
      }//if
    } // while

    input.close ( );




}//countvowels

int countnonvowels(int &k){//counts the non-vowels

ifstream input;
char kar;
int countnonvowels = 0;

input.open ("input.txt",ios::in); //open the file


    kar = input.get ( ); 
    while ( ! input.eof ( ) ) { //same while loop
        kar = input.get ( );

      if( kar != 'e' or kar != 'a' or kar != 'i' or kar != 'o' or kar != 'u' ){ //now i want the counter to roll if it is NOT a vowel
            countnonvowels++;
            cout << kar << endl;
      }
      if (kar == '*'){ //if a "*" appears, I want the vowels to be counted again
            countvowels(k);
            return 0;

      }//if
    } // while

input.close ( );


}//countnonvowels


int main ( ) {

countvowels(2);

    return 0;
} // main
```

The problem here is that I get an endless loop: The file gets checked for vowels, it see's a [star sign], starts counting the non-vowels from the start of the text, see's the [star sign] again and starts counting the vowels from the start of the textfile etc...

The star-sign (shift+8) makes everything cursive apparently, I hope it's clear which one I mean.

Comment: Pass the open "file" (`iostream`? `FILE *`?) to the other function.

Comment: I just added a bit, sorry for not doing that at the start. 

@crashmstr that's exactly what I want! But how can I tell the other function to continue obtaining characters where the last one left off?

Comment: Open the file *outside* of these two functions, then pass the `input` to those functions (and they will continue from where it last was).

Comment: That does stop the endless looping, but the non-vowel counting function (see above) won't respond. I'm not sure what you mean by "pass the input to those functions", do you mean I should be able to just use the "input.get()" in the second function without opening it?

Comment: if `input` is a variable in `main` and you add `ifstream &input` as a *parameter* to your functions, then in those functions you can use `input.get()` and not restart from the beginning of the file.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a short example given that you know how to check if the letter is a vowel or not. I'm leaving modifying it to work for a whole file to you since I suspect this is a homework question.

```
   void countLetters(const string& line)
    {
       int vowels, nonVowels;
       vowels = nonVowels = 0;
       bool countingVowels = true;
       for (int position = 0; position < line.length(); position++)
       {
          if (countingVowels && isVowel(line[position])
          {
             vowels++;
          }
          else if (!countingVowels && !isVowel(line[position]))
          {
             nonVowels++;
          } 
          else if (line[position] == '*')
          {
             countingVowels = !countingVowels;
          }
       }
       cout << vowels << " "<< nonVowels<<endl;
    }
```